# Popen polling blocking my stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout, popen

To prove a concept to myself I wrote this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import json

queue = []

command1 = ['python', 'C:\Desktop\testing_popen\time_delay.py']

command2 = ['python', 'C:\Desktop\testing_popen\no_time_delay.py']

queue.append(Popen(command1, stdout=PIPE))

queue.append(Popen(command2, stdout=PIPE))

while len(queue) > 0:

    while queue[0].poll() is None:

        queue.append(queue.pop(0))

    print json.loads(queue.pop(0).communicate()[0])
```

> > output from no_time_delay.py
> >
> > output from time_delay.py

This works exactly as I wish so that elements further down the queue aren't held up but elements closer to the front that take longer to process. I'm using the queue as a way of throttling the process so that I don't use up all the CPU but I always want the maximum number of processes running.

I then wanted to implement this is in a project

I have to process 200 records but I only want 10 scripts running at a time as not to overload the CPU. Each script can only handle 10 records.

So..

I create a queue and

```
while len(scripts_to_be_processed) > 0:
    if len(queue) < 10:
        queue.append(Popen(command,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE))
    else:
        while queue[0].poll() is None:
            queue.append(queue.pop(0))
        function_to_process_out(queue.pop(0).communicate()[0])
```

and then process the scripts remaining in the queue outside of this loop..

The process involves ingestion of an xlsx file, I can see from my task manager that the processes have finished but the main script coordinating the instances only receives None back from the polling.

I have updated the script to write the output to a file at the end of a run. The file will be written to before the std.out.write but not after so it is my theory that the constant polling might be blocking the script from outputting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers

**Edit**

Update: My issue lay in using the PIPE as my stdout. The buffer file filled up and caused a deadlock. I fixed this by writing each individual record to stdout with a newline delimiter and creating a thread for each subprocessto listen to each subprocess' stdout by calling .readline(). This allowed me to constantly empty the temporary buffer files and avoid deadlock.